# std::copy issue I don't knowwhy this error happens

Tags: c++, c++11

1. I copied the struct into a vector and put it back into the struct. Why did this bug occur? use `std::copy` incorrectly?
2. When copying, I used `std::copy`, and I copied structures one by one.

This is the code:

```
struct test_msg
{
  int32_t msg_type =0; 
  int32_t msg_id =0; 
  int32_t src = 0 ; 
  int32_t dst = 0;

  std::string data;

  bool Serialize(std::vector<char> &out) {
    out.clear();
    std::copy(&msg_type, &msg_type + sizeof(msg_type), std::back_inserter(out));
    std::copy(&msg_id,&msg_id + sizeof(msg_id), std::back_inserter(out));
    std::copy(&src,&src + sizeof(src), std::back_inserter(out));
    std::copy(&dst,&dst + sizeof(dst), std::back_inserter(out));

    std::copy(json_string.begin(),json_string.end(), std::back_inserter(out));

    return true;
  };

  bool Deserialize(std::vector<char> &out) {
    int last_index = 0;

    std::copy(out.begin() + last_index, out.begin() +last_index + sizeof(msg_type), &msg_type);          last_index += sizeof(msg_type);
    std::copy(out.begin() + last_index, out.begin() +last_index + sizeof(msg_id), &msg_id);              last_index += sizeof(msg_id);
    std::copy(out.begin() + last_index, out.begin() +last_index + sizeof(src), &src);                    last_index += sizeof(src);
    std::copy(out.begin() + last_index, out.begin() +last_index + sizeof(dst), &dst);                    last_index += sizeof(dst);
   // std::copy(out.begin() + last_index, out.begin() +last_index + sizeof(synchronous), &synchronous);    last_index += sizeof(synchronous);
    std::copy(out.begin() + last_index, out.end(),  std::back_inserter(json_string));

    return true;
  };
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  testmsg msg;
  msg.msg_type =11;
  msg.msg_id =22;
  msg.src =33;
  msg.dst =44;
  msg.json_string = "this is test!this is test!this is test!\0";

  std::vector<char> data;
  msg.Serialize(data);

  IpcJsonMessage msg2;
  msg2.Deserialize(data);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: _"Why did this bug occur?"_ - What bug? My bet is on `Deserialize`, where `std::copy` should cause invalid writes. But please add a proper problem description.

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would also help.

Comment: The “begin iterator” and “past-the-end iterator” for a single object `x` are `&x` and `&x + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're using `std::copy` to copy `int32s` which will iterate int32s but you're thinking it will iterate bytes:

```
std::copy(&msg_type, &msg_type + sizeof(msg_type), std::back_inserter(out));
```

In this case you will most likely be copying 4 non-contiguous bytes - from offsets 0, 4, 8, 12 (LSB first), since the iteration will work in the same fashion as when you're incrementing C pointers (i.e. `int32* pX;  pX++;` will increment pX by one int32 -> 4 bytes).  Each iteration will load an int32 from memory but only add the least significant byte to the char vector.

It helps to think of how the std::copy unrolls:

```
int32* pIter;
int32* pEnd;   //pIter+4 i.e 16 bytes ahead of pIter
vector<char> dest;

while (pIter < pEnd)
{
    int32 value = *pIter;
    dest.push_back (value);  //loses the upper 24 bits of value
    pIter++;
}
```

See here for a full explanation: [Copy Memory to std::copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523153/copy-memory-to-stdcopy)

Here is a screendump from running a snippet in Visual Studio:

[image]

---

In terms of a solution to the problem, take a look at: [Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c)